# Why do we have implicit receiver in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, oop

I have two questions regarding Ruby core OOP concepts.

1. I understand the differences between explicit call  (i.e. with self) and implicit call (i.e. without initialized class object or self in an instance method) of a method. When we have explicit receivers that do very neat and clear job of receiving a method with self (since it refers to the current object) rather than implicit ones (which I believe is very uncertain in situations like when to use method or variable of same name initialized), then why do we still have to call methods implicitly? Is it just a preference or is it necessary because of proper usage of private and public methods?.
2. In general, OOP private methods are bound within the class itself and cannot be accessed in subclasses or outside. However, those methods that need to be private but also need to be accessed in subclasses then protected methods are used over there. But in Ruby, both private and
   protected methods are accessed in inherited classes, and the only difference is that private methods can only be called implicitly and protected methods can either be called implicitly or explicitly. I don't understand the philosophy over here that only because of implicit calling functionality in ruby, general definitions of private methods differ?

Comment: For (1) - the ruby community doesn't adhere to the "explicit is better than implicit" principle. You will see things that aren't clear if you lack context, but are more concise and "beautiful" (some would say) if you have a good understanding. For (2) - what does "in general OOP" mean? Java? I don't remember the last time I saw `protected` method in ruby code. I would agree it's a bit useless, but I don't think it's a less correct interpretation of private and protected. Ask yourself - why should private methods be unaccessible in subclasses?

Comment: Thanks for your answer but For (1) I understand that the authorized answer can only provided by Matz himself cause still I don't get why there are things which are unclear but beautiful.

Comment: For (2) Yes I mean C# and Java. In my perspective private methods are implementations which need to be secured and encapsulated that they are only used inside public methods so with the protected methods when Parent private methods need to be used in Subclass, I think this is the basic purpose in Java, C# but in Ruby it differs with a slight difference and that is because of implicit and explicit receivers? I am sorry still I am unclear with your second answer.

Comment: For (1) - you can still call methods without an explicit receiver (aka `this.`) in java/c#. As for why `self.` is not "beautiful" - you repeat yourself over and over again. It's verbose. In normal speech you strive to use as little words as possible that make your point clear. Unlike js, ruby has sensible and easy to follow rules for what `self` is in the current context. As a rubyist, your target audience is other rubyists. Hence `self` is redundant. Additionally, if explicit receiver was always required (like python), ruby wouldn't be as good for writing DSLs.

Comment: For (2) - I simply disagree that encapsulation has to do with hiding private things from children. A subclass is a further specification of its parent, not an outsider. Inside the definition of a `Cow`, you are still referring to a `Mammal`. Hence, you should still be able to reason about the mammalian digestive track if you need to, even if the abstraction you provide in the end is "stuff goes in, energy is absorbed, stuff goes out".

Comment: For(2) - I think I agree with @ndn that 'private' is not supposed to hide things from children. 'private' is a thing which is supposed to hide things from outsider and not your family. Languages like Java/C++/C# provide a higher level of control for cases where even inter-family privacy is required and I think that can be attributed to these languages being `compiled` as against `interpreted`, so to make additional checks on a private(or family private) method being called in a wrong context. `protected` in ruby I suppose just serves the appetite of Java/C++/C# migrants, and is used rarely.

Answer (score 6):

I think you have a slight misunderstanding of the purpose of protected methods.  Protected methods can be called from methods of another instance of the same class.

```
class Person

  def initialize(name, age)
    @name = name
    @age = age
  end

  def older_than?(other_person)
    age > other_person.age
  end

  protected

  def age
    @age
  end

end

mother = Person.new('Carole', 34)
father = Person.new('George', 37)
```

If you try...

```
mother.age
=>NoMethodError: protected method `age' called for #<Person:0x0000000327daa0 @name="Carole", @age=34>
```

So you cannot, externally, call the `#age` method.

But you can do...

```
father.older_than?(mother)
=> true
```

So the `father` object was able to call the `mother` object `#age` method, because he is an object of the same class `Person`.

Answer (score 1):

In the discussion below, recall that the only way to call an instance method with an implicit receiver (`self`) is to do so from within an instance method of the same class.

The question is why Ruby was designed to permit most<sup>1</sup> instance methods to be called with an implicit receiver.

One would probably have to ask Matz to get an authoritative answer, but my guess is that it traces back to the way private instance methods were implemented. Requiring that they be called with an implicit receiver was seen (I'm guessing) as a simple way to prevent them from being called from anywhere other than from within an instance method of the same class.

But if private methods must be called with an implicit receiver, in the interest of consistency wouldn't it have made sense to permit (nearly all) public and protected instance methods to be called with an implicit receiver?

Some Rubiests see the use of the explicit receiver `self` as redundant, and therefore use an implicit receiver (except where `self.` is required). Others see the use of implicit receivers as a potential source of confusion, so use `self.`, knowing (or possibly not knowing), that is optional. So far as I know, all core Ruby methods implemented in Ruby use implicit receivers. Those in the first camp might argue that using `self.` redundantly is akin to saying "Meet me at the blue wall that is colored blue".

<sup>1 There are a handful of cases where the explicit receiver `self` is required to avoid ambiguity. The two most common are when invoking the method `class` (considering `class` is also a keyword) and invoking a setter, which Ruby might otherwise confuse with the assignment of a value to a newly-created local variable. Another example is that we cannot write `Array` methods `def a; [1]; end` nor `def a; [](1); end`. Again, an explicit receiver is needed: `self[1]` or `self.[](1)`.</sup>